# Ruby-on-Rails: populate select box based off prior select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototype

I have a set of 3 collection_selects that I would like to filter the next select. Upon selecting an item in the first select box, it should limit the possible values of the second and third select boxes.

A similar data model would be as follows...

Tables, and fields

- Lock

  - lock_id
  - brand_id
  - master_id
  - regular_id
- Lock Brand

  - brand_id
- Master Key

  - master_id
  - brand_id
- Regular Key

  - regular_id
  - brand_id

So while filling in the form for adding a new Lock there would be select boxes for brand, master, and regular.  Upon selecting a brand, it would then limit the master and regular keys to those that are only of the selected brand.

I've found a couple partial examples of how to do this, however none are complete. I'd appreciate a complete example of how to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is bind the selects with an event listener that fires off an ajax request populating the other 2 partials containing the subsequent selects. i.e.

```
<%= form_for @thing, :remote => true do, :update => 'second_form' |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'form_partial', :value => 'form_2' %> 
  <%= select_tag :some_param, [[a,a],[b,b],[c,c]] :class => 'submittable' %> 
  <%= f.label :checked %>
  <%= thing.name %>
<% end %>
<div id='second_form'>
</div>
<div id='third_form'>
</div>

class ThingController < ApplicationController
  def update
    checkboxes = some_logic_to_select_checkboxes from params[:some_params]
    render :partial => params[:form_partial], :locals => {:select_menu => select_menu}
  end
end

$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  return false;
});
```

Your form partial should contain your forms populated with whatever selects you want enabled. Thought is was redundant to just repeat the form.

Comment: I was looking for how to do this with drop-down select boxes, not check boxes. Can you update accordingly please?

Comment: You could have easily looked up the helper for 'select' instead of checkbox and made the substitution. The theory should have been good enough to get you started.