# RAILS 4 Dynamic generating of select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two select tags/controls and I need the second select tag options to be dynamically generate based on the selection of first

For example I want to make after selecting a car brand in first select, the second must show the models of selected car brand, But I have not been able to do it please help

Comment: you need to call ajax onchange of first dropdown,based on the selection return the associated objects and make js call to update html of other dropdown....this is what you need.... :)

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155268/ruby-on-rails-populate-select-box-based-off-prior-select

Answer (score 0):

Please watch rails cast #88 dynamic select menus revised. The method you need to do this called grouped_collection_select

This method along with the proper coffee script (or JavaScript if you prefer that more than coffeescript) discussed in the video will complete exactly what you're looking for